# Mocking a wrapper time function

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have a created a minor wrapper function for the php `time()` method in my class

```
class MyClass
{
    public function myFuncion($unixTimeStamp)
    {
        $pending = $this->isPending($unixTimeStamp)

        // data manipulation

        return $result
    }

    protected function isPending($unixTimeStamp)
    {
        if ($unixTimeStamp > $this->currentTime()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function currentTime()
    {
        return time();
    }
}
```

I want to test the public function `myFunction()` in this class but I am at a bit of a loss how I can mock the currentTime method without mocking the SUT itself (MyClass)

What is the correct way of doing this? I felt creating a time class with a single method (getCurrentTime) and injecting it into `MyClass` while correct, was excessive as I only check the time in one place in my code.

Is this the best method regardless?

**EDIT:** I am considering making a `time` trait as it [looks like](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-traits-and-abstract-classes) PhpUnit can mock this. Still unsure if this is overkill for use in a single method..

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Partial mock object of your tested class in order to modify the behaviour only of the selected method (the `currentTime` method). For this purpose you can use the `setMethods` of the [Mock Builder API](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html):

> setMethods(array $methods) can be called on the Mock Builder object to
>   specify the methods that are to be replaced with a configurable test
>   double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed. If you call
>   setMethods(NULL), then no methods will be replaced.

So try this code (suppose the `myFunction` return the result of the `isPending` method):

```
class MyClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function itShouldReturnTrueIfPendingState()
    {
        $currentTime = (new \DateTime('now -1 year'))->getTimestamp();

        /** @var MyClass|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $myClass */
        $myClass = $this->getMockBuilder(MyClass::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['currentTime'])
            ->getMock();

        $myClass
            ->method('currentTime')
            ->willReturn($currentTime);

        $this->assertTrue($myClass->myFunction(time()));
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function itShouldReturnFalseIfNotState()
    {
        $currentTime = (new \DateTime('now +1 year'))->getTimestamp();


        /** @var MyClass|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $myClass */
        $myClass = $this->getMockBuilder(MyClass::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['currentTime'])
            ->getMock();

        $myClass
            ->method('currentTime')
            ->willReturn($currentTime);

        $this->assertFalse($myClass->myFunction(time()));
    }
```

Comment: I have decided to create a class and inject it over partially mocking the SUT, although your suggestion helped a different issue, so thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can override the `time()` function in the namespace level. Check https://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2011/03/php-mocking-built-in-functions-like-time-in-unit-tests/

but the downfall is that every time we call `time()` it will return the mocked time :)

```
namespace MyClass;

function time()
{
    return MyClassTest::$mockTime ?: \time();
}

class MyClassTest extends TestCase{

    public static $mockTime;

    public function test_my_function(){   
        self::$mockTime = '08:10';
        $myClass = new MyClass();
        //$myClass->currentTime() //will return 08:10
        //do something with my function
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but if you are able to install php extensions on your environment you can use https://github.com/slope-it/clock-mock, which works transparently with 0 modifications to your code. At that point, you can remove `currentTime()` and just use `time()`.